# How many 4 letter words can we make from BANANAS

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

As the title suggests, I want to know the value of possible permutations without repetition given the word BANANAS

BA<sub>1</sub>N<sub>1</sub>A<sub>2</sub>N<sub>2</sub>A<sub>3</sub>S

so for example to word A<sub>1</sub>N<sub>1</sub>A<sub>2</sub>S is the  A<sub>3</sub>N<sub>1</sub>A<sub>2</sub>S and we want to exclude it from our total value.

How would I calculate this, I've tried 7*6*5*4 /(3!)(2!) but I think this value is too small.

Comment: Maybe $4^2$? not sure.

Comment: Are you looking for 4 letter sets, or 4 letter words? There are only (afaik) 2 (English) 4 letter words you can make from bananas, *BANS* and *NABS*. So, 2 ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using exponential generating functions, since there are 3 A's, 2 N's, 1 B, and 1 S, we get

$g_e(x)=\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}\right)\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}\right)(1+x)^2=1+4x+7x^2+\frac{43}{6}x^3+\frac{19}{4}x^4+\cdots$,

so there are $(4!)(\frac{19}{4})=\color{red}{114}$ words of length 4.

---

Alternatively, we can consider the number of A's used:

1) 3 A's: There are 3 choices for the remaining letter, giving $4\cdot3=12$ cases

2) 2 A's: With 2 N's, there are 6 cases, and with BN, SN, or SB we get $3\cdot12=36$ additional cases

3) 1 A: with 2 N's, we get $2\cdot12=24$ cases, and with NBS we get $4!=24$ additional cases

4) 0 A's: this gives $4\cdot3=12$ cases

Therefore the total is given by $12+42+48+12=\color{red}{114}$ cases.

Comment: Can you explain how ur GF approach works? I'm very interested!

Comment: See Sec. 11.2 in http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ebender/CombText/ch-11.pdf, and especially Ex. 6.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a distinct four letter string from $\sf AAABNNS$ by selecting then arranging:
$$\sf (AAA[B|S|N]) \mid (AANN) \mid ([AA|NN]BS) \mid ([AAN|NNA][B|S]) \mid (ANBS)$$

Count the ways for each case, then add.

- Triple and singleton (3 choice of singletons)

  - $\binom 11\binom 3 1\frac{4!}{3!~1!}$
- Two pair
- Pair and two singletons
- Four singletons

Answer (score 5):

Okay, bring out the big and boring guns.

We can have:

No multiple letters.  Thus words using B,A,N,S.  There are $4!$ such words.

One pair of double letters.  That letter can be be A or N, and for the remaining two letters we can omit (A or N), B, or A.  So there are $2*3$ choices of letters and for each choice of letter there are $4*3$ ways to place the two non repeating letters.  So $6*4*3$ such words.

Two pairs of A and N.  There are ${4 \choose 2}$ choices to arrange AANN.

Three letters.  A  and then N,B,S for the remaining letter.  That is $3$  chooses of letters and $4$ choices of where to put the one non repeating letter.  $3*4$ total.

So there are $4! + 6*4*3 + {4\choose2} + 3*4 = 24 + 72 + 6 + 12 = 114$ total.

Comment: You correctly found that there are $\binom{4}{2}$ arrangements with two pairs, but $\binom{4}{2} = 6$.  Also, there are only two N's, so the only way to use three identical letters is to use the three A's.  You can choose their positions in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways and have three choices for filling the open position.

Comment: Gore dang it.  The first was a typo and second an oversight.  I'll fix.